# Linux command to display webcam video output in full screen?

Tags: linux, video, webcam

I'm using an rpi1 (running raspbian lite and jwm) with a USB webcam hooked to a CRT TV to display its output. Up until now I've been using Camorama which works nicely, but I lose some of the measly 640x480 screen resolution for the title bar of the app, and also some of it below due to the window manager showing buttons etc that I don't need. Is there any way I can simply show up the video output of the device in a full screen window? so I can just add it to the startup of the window manager and run it on top of it. I really don't need any of the features that Camorama has because all I want is to display video ala security camera.

Answer (score 3):

### Display webcam output from Linux

*Note: Adjust with and height where necessary*

```
mplayer tv:// -tv driver=v4l:width=352:height=288
```

or

```
mplayer tv:// -tv driver=v4l2:width=640:height=480:device=/dev/video0:fps=30:outfmt=yuy2
```

### How to Record a Screencast & Convert it to an mpeg

```
ffmpeg -f x11grab -r 25 -s 640x480 -i :0.0 /tmp/VideoOutput.mpg
```

Record audio and video from webcam using ffmpeg

### Record webcam audio using ALSA, MP3 encoded & video as MPEG-4.

```
ffmpeg -f alsa -r 16000 -i hw:2,0 -f video4linux2 -s 800x600 -i /dev/video0 -r 30 -f avi -vcodec mpeg4 -vtag xvid -sameq -acodec libmp3lame -ab 96k myVideo.avi
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: The first command worked, but the color looks wrong. I also tried adding outfmt=yuy2 to the first command but the color is still wrong. My webcam is a Logitech c160.

Comment: @Webodan the `outfmt=yuy2` is output format of your webcam, substitute yuy2 to your camera output format.